# How to make the content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded work with @RequestBody annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When the content type is application/json,@RequestBody can read the request body and deserialized into an Object, but the content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded， spring-mvc can not support this content type with @RequestBody annotation.

In my project, I encountered this problem, I want to support both of them at the same time, but I don't want to lose the convenience of @RequestBody.

Is there another way to support these two content type and like @RequestBody can auto deserialized request body into an Object?

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public String test(@RequestBody User user) {
  return user.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another way to support these two content type and like
>   @RequestBody can auto deserialized request body into an Object?

Negative.

What you *can* do is use [FormHttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html) to deserialize into a `MultiValueMap<String, String>`. You can then write an transformer to take that and create a `User` object.

Comment: Spring mvc supports the deserialization of application/x-www-form-urlencoded and also supports the deserialization of application/json. Why not do it at the same time? I am very confused

Comment: Post a full example of the body of the request and we can take a look at how to maybe automate this some more, if possible. It’s difficult to do anything without seeing what we are dealing with!